# Process injections. Windows

Tags: windows, code-injection

I know how to inject my code into other process using system calls - just get module handle using **GetModuleHandle**, and get proc address using **GetProcAddress**. By that address I can write jump instructions to my function.
But I need to inject into function of target executable. I have function's offset inside PE, know section. How to calculate needed addres in runtime to write jump instructions?
Thanks!

Comment: The module handle is the address of the start of the module, so if you know the offset you can just add them together.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot :) How to mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module handle is the address of the start of the module, so if you know the offset you can just add them together.